# How to skip successive elements in a java stream?

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming

I've been trying to incorporate more functional programming into what I do because of the of the side-effect-free nature of the code I write and its utility in concurrent code.  I came across the need to filter out successive elements of a java stream and couldn't come up with a functional approach better than a plain old imperative approach.  Say I have a program that logs its arguments and I want to filter out 2 successive elements.  For example, `-o anOption, -k aSecretKeyWhoseValueWeShouldNotLog, -a anotherOption`.  What I want in the log is `-o anOption, -a anotherOption`.

I came up with several approaches, but none of them was as understandable as using a for loop that indexed past the stuff I needed to filter out.

This seems like a fairly common thing to want to do.  Is there a pattern, using java streams or anything else, that is commonly used for this kind of thing?

Thanks,

Here's what I ended up with.

```
static String filterSecretKeyOutOfCommandLineLogString(final String[] args) {
    return joinArgsToString(filterOptionAndValueOutOfCommandLineLogString(SECRET_KEY, args));
}

private static String joinArgsToString(final String[] args) {
    return Joiner.on(ARG_JOINER_DELIMITER).join(args);
}

private static String[] filterOptionAndValueOutOfCommandLineLogString(final Option option, final String[] args) {
    final List<String> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

    final int numArgs = args.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < numArgs; ++i) {
        if (Arguments.matchesOption(option, args[i])) {
            ++i;
         } else {
             filteredList.add(args[i]);
         }
     }

     return filteredList.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

Comment: can you please provide your imperative approach to better illustrate your description.

Comment: What do you mean by "skip successive elements"?

Comment: Could you show us the imperative approach you've come up with?  That can be used as a starting point for a stream-based approach (and if a stream-based approach would get you any wins, really).

Comment: Say I have an array { "-o", "anOption", "-k", "secretKey", "-a", "anotherOption" }, what I want to end up with is another array omitting -k and secretKey.  Something like { "-o", "anOption", "-a", "anotherOption" }

Comment: So that presumes your `Option` object gets populated with a flag field for `"k"` and a value field for `"secretKey"`.  If it doesn't, that'd be the ideal place to start.

Comment: Your presumption is correct — Option is populated with a key value list tuple.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Take every nth element from a Java 8 stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31602425/take-every-nth-element-from-a-java-8-stream)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is any better than what you already have. Given that the input is a `String[]` and the (intermediate) output you want is also a `String[]` a simple-hearted translation to Java streams could be

```
static String[] filterOptionAndValue(String option, String args[]) {
    return IntStream.range(0, args.length)
            .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)
            .mapToObj(i -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(args[i], args[i + 1]))
            .filter(e -> !option.equals(e.getKey()))
            .flatMap(e -> Stream.of(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
            .toArray(String[]::new);
}

public static void main(String... env) {

    String[] args = {"-o", "opt1", "-k", "secret", "-a", "opt2"};

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(filterOptionAndValue("-k", args)));
}
```

> [-o, opt1, -a, opt2]

Comment: Ah.  I had something along the same lines, though where you used an Abstract map, I used a pair.  What I missed was the flatMap following the second filter.  Many thanks.