# Reading every fourth String element into ArrayList of Integer type in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I am looking to read the following ArrayList of String into an ArrayList of Int type:

```
[1000, 31000, 3, Texas, 1042, 12180.06, 3, Texas, 1062, 13240.45, 2, Texas, 1200, 36000, 2, Maryland, 1327, 19800.56, 2, Alaska, 1483, 22458.23, 7, Texas, 1900, 17000.09, 3, Washington, 2000, 16910.00, 2, Vermont, 2112, 23125, 4, Alaska, 2500, 20001, 5, Hawaii, 3000, 21330.00, 3, Texas, 3210, 13200, 1, Minnesota, 3600, 77500, 4, California, 3601, 11970, 2, Illinois, 4000, 25750.00, 4, Florida, 4724, 8900, 3, Oklahoma, 6217, 45000.70, 2, Texas, 9280, 6200, 1, Vermont, 5000, 30170.00, 2, Hawaii, 5100, 30170.05, 5, Arkansas, 5601, 51970, 9, Illinois, 5724, 66900, 3, Florida, 5217, 10002.68, 2, Texas, 5280, 70000, 1, Washington, 5000, 100000, 10, Hawaii, 5200, 25000.4, 3, Texas, 5230, 120000, 6, California, 6641, 85000, 7, Alaska, 7000, 45500, 4, Maryland, 7100, 56500, 3, Illinois, 7205, 50100.65, 8, Arkansas, 8110, 110005.9, 8, Texas, 8340, 70100.25, 9, Iowa, 9101, 67590.40, 6, Texas, 9220, 35000.58, 8, Arkansas, 9300, 22000.69, 4, Iowa, 9400, 19490.00, 1, Hawaii, 9400, 55490.00, 4, Pennsylvania]
```

Is there a way to read every fourth element so that 31000, 12180.06, 13240.45, 36000, ... etc. gets read into ArrayList income, cast as an int data type?

I'm coming from Python and am new to Java and can't figure out how to correctly do this. The following code is outputting a list of every fourth number starting from 1 right now...

```
List<String> surveyData = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(contents.split("\\s+")));
        
        ArrayList<Integer> income = new ArrayList<>();
        
        for (int i = 1; i < surveyData.size(); i+=4)
        {
            income.add(i);
        }
        System.out.println(income);
```

Output currently:

```
[1, 5, 9, 13, 17, 21, 25, 29, 33, 37, 41, 45,...]
```

Expected Output:

```
[31000, 12180.06, 13240.45, 36000, 19800.56... ]
```

Very important that the data is stored to an ArrayList!

***UPDATE
Reading in data from file in this format:

```
1000  31000  3 Texas
1042  12180.06  3 Texas
1062  13240.45  2 Texas
1200  36000  2 Maryland
1327  19800.56  2 Alaska
1483  22458.23  7 Texas
1900  17000.09  3 Washington
...
```

With this code:

```
public void readFile()
    {
        String contents = null;
        try 
        {
            contents = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("Program10.txt")));
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        List<String> surveyData = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(contents.split("\\s+")));
        
        double[] income = new double[surveyData.size()];
        double sum = 0;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < surveyData.size(); i+=4)
        {
            income[i] = Double.parseDouble(surveyData.get(i));
            sum += income[i];
        }
// Calculate & Print the Average Income
        averageIncome = sum / (income.length / 4);
        // Outputting the total rainfall for the year
        System.out.printf("%nAverage Income is %.2f", averageIncome);
```

prints the correct average ( I checked) and is parsing all other items to double as 0.0. Note that I've income.length / 4 to skip extraneous elements.

Comment: possible duplicate (depending on your experience with Python, you may be familiar with streams/functional style... In Java, it is easy to convert a list to a stream): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31602425

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The i represents an integer that simply acts as a counter as you go through the for loop. It does not represent the list's elements themselves, like a for-each loop in python would. You can use it as an index however, to access the element at the point in the list/array. For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < surveyData.size(); i+=4)
{
    income.add(Integer.parseInt(surveyData.get(i))); //parseInt converts string to int, get returns element at a specific position in the list
}
System.out.println(income);
```

Keep in mind that for-each loops do exist in Java as well, of course with different syntax.
Here are some helpful links on Java for loops, arrays, and array lists: https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_for_loop.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_arrays.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_arraylist.asp

As always, you could refer to the official Java documentation.

Comment: Thank you @Sankeetth! With i+=4, I'm trying to read in every fourth element, but it looks like every element is being added. Any idea why that's happening?

Comment: Hmm, that's odd, because as long as you're calling .get(i) and increasing i by 4 each time, it should work. Update your question with your current code so I can see where it might be going wrong.

Comment: Very strange, does the ***UPDATE shed any insight? @Sankeeth

Comment: I see you changed income to an array. Keep in mind that this will mean that all elements aside from every fourth will remain at the default value of 0. The program seems to work on my end though when I modify it to take the input using Scanner (as I don't have access to your file), what issue are you having with it?