# Java Stream to pick values at even pointers

Tags: java, stream

I need to pick values placed at even pointers in list using Stream.

List test = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.addAll(test, "aa","bb","cc","dd","ee");

Using Stream I need to print
aa
cc
ee

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Take every nth element from a Java 8 stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31602425/take-every-nth-element-from-a-java-8-stream)

Comment: You don't want to do that. Just write a for loop.

Comment: @rzwitserloot it was asked in an interview :)

Comment: And that should be your answer then: This isn't a suitable job for the stream API.